# RecyclerView scroll in incorrect direction when new element is inserted

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database, smooth-scrolling, firebaseui

I use `smoothScrollToPosition` to scroll RecyclerView. It does scroll every time a new entry is inserted; but to the top, not to the bottom, which is the direction i want.

```
    list_chat = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_chat);
    //Set up Layout Manager
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    list_chat.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    //set adapter
    list_chat.setAdapter(adapter);
    //set scroll
    list_chat.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            list_chat.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount());
        }
    });
```

The adapter is from Firebase

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatItem, ChatRecylerViewHolder>(ChatItem.class,R.layout.chat_item
        ,ChatRecylerViewHolder.class,queryChat  ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ChatRecylerViewHolder viewHolder, ChatItem model, int position) {
            viewHolder.tvAuthorChat.setText(model.chatAuthor);
            viewHolder.tvContentChat.setText(model.chatContent);
        }
    };
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look If it doesn't help leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the answer.
First, the old problem with my question: i thought `list_chat.post` is called whenever an item is inserted (turn out that is wrong). The reason for it keeps scrolling top is `linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);`
Thus, the question comes down to **Where to call the scrolling ?**
The answer is : Since adapter manages data, it makes sense to guess that adapter will notify the insertion. 
Here is the code

```
adapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
            list_chat.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

You do notice you are using `linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);` this mean you first position is at the bottom. I suggest you a better option.

RecycleView didn't work the way listView work, you can scroll it with your layout manager something like this

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position,offset);
```

Which position is the position you want to scroll to, offset is the offset within the current position. You could just use with one parameter as well.

```
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(position);
```

Comment: At first, i thought list_chat.post is the event when a new element is inserted. But as i just test, it does not. So now my question is "where to pull the update linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(position); ?"

Comment: in what event, the scrolling line can be called ? I could put in inside Send button; but that only update for new message sends from me. How to get the event when others send message ?

Comment: The reason it keeps scrolling top is because linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
Commenting it out keep the screen remain position. But still, where to call the update scrolling ? 
list_chat.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getItemCount()); does work for special testing. So i do not think
linearLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(position);
is the answer.

Comment: If you want scroll your recycleView that the answer. Now your second question already out of your current question topic. I don't know anything about Firebase database so I can't help you bro.

Comment: Thank for your help. But as i point out, setting the scroll from the RecyclerView or LinearLayoutManager are the same (actually i do not test with LinearLayoutManager yet). Thus, your answer actually does not answer the question. 
Instead, the answer is where to put the scrolling code.